# Change value in shared library with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following `lib.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double var = 4;

double* fun() {
    printf("%zd %f\n", &var, var);
    return &var;
}
```

and the following `main.py`:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.so')
fun = lib.fun
fun.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

print ctypes.addressof(fun().contents)
```

How can I, inside the `.py`, change the `double` stored at the address of `fun().contents`, e.g., set `var` to `10.2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will change the value:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('x')
fun = lib.fun
fun.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
v = fun()
v.contents.value = 2.0
v = fun()
```

Output (note for C function I used `%p` instead of `%zd`):

```
000007FEFAC14000 4.000000
000007FEFAC14000 2.000000
```